# Modern neanderthals

Tags: science-based, biology, evolution, humans

Homo  neanderthalensis were an extinct species of homo that lived on earth until 40'000 years ago.Neanderthal humans were larger than Cro-Magnon and had bigger brains to sustain their stronger and bigger muscles. Theories suggest Neanderthals also had bigger kidneys and livers to support their meat based diets rich in protein and extremely poor in carbohydrates or fats. Other than that they were pretty much the same as the Cro-Magnon so here my question arises.

One of the theories of how* Neanderthals were killed is due to climate change, their bodies were adapted for the hostile cold Europe and couldn't survive on a completely new environment. But, what if the neanderthals spread around the world too before going extinct and survived until today without melting in a hybrid species with the sapiens? How would they have evolved until today?

I'm not interested in their relationships with homo sapiens sapiens unless the relationships with us conditioned their biological evolution. But I think it is unlikely as we are a younger species than them,plus for the most time on earth there were more than one human [species](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvIfo.jpg) and other than inbreeding they didn't seem to condition each other this drastically.

Comment: "*I'm not interested in their relationships with homo sapiens sapiens unless the relationships with us conditioned their biological evolution.*" Would a program of genocide be considered "conditioned their biological evolution"? You have two distinct species (in your hypothetical; the jury is still out on that) with similar brain power, tool-using capabilities, and ecological niches both vying for resources and overall planetary dominance. And one of those species is **us**. We commit genocide *on ourselves*; how do you think we're going to interact with them?

Comment: “how would they have evolved” has been asked in other contests, and is far too open ended for WB.  It’s anybody’s guess, and that’s nit the format of this Stack Exchange.  (But maybe the proposed [What-if](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/95463/what-if) SE would have been a better choice.)

Comment: @NicolBolas We don't have yet the technology to wipe out humanity, so I assume we didn't have it for  our entire history in the past. Maybe if you think warfare would have influenced their biological evolution then, sure I'm ok with that.

Comment: Homo Neanderthalensis isn't a subspecies of Homo sapiens, Homo sapiens idaltu is

Comment: maybe you should consider our evolution since some of us walked out of Africa. Or how much we are expected to have to evolve to survive global warming.

Comment: Competition for food and especially mates will be tough, despite human tiny frame the shrewd and the cunning wins brute and strength over time. Natural selection accidentally pry open a Pandora box, in this zero sum game aka world a selfish gene is born.

Comment: "other than inbreeding they didn't seem to condition each other this drastically." - why would you think that? Interbreeding means they lived in the same areas. This means they competed for food. Competing species always affect each other evolution.

Answer (score 7):

The answer may be "the modern world." :-)
The climate change theory isn't necessarily right. There's a competing theory that they simply bred into modern humans and were outbred by us. Part of that theory is based on DNA evidence. We know there was at least some interbreeding because:
https://genographic.nationalgeographic.com/neanderthal/
"Everyone living outside of Africa today has a small amount of Neanderthal in them, carried as a living relic of these ancient encounters. A team of scientists comparing the full genomes of the two species concluded that most Europeans and Asians have between 1 to 4 percent Neanderthal DNA. Indigenous sub-Saharan Africans have no Neanderthal DNA because their ancestors did not migrate through Eurasia."

Some pockets of modern humans have greater concentrations of this DNA than others. Those would be your modern Neanderthals.

Answer (score 1):

This could drift off into "opinion based" since the hard evidence is difficult to find.

Based on what we know and some informed speculation, it is well understood that the Neanderthals were generally as "smart" as the Ancestors, with similar body size and even a slight edge in the average size of the brain. However, looking at the archeological remains, it is quite clear there were some very large differences between the Neanderthals and the Ancestors.

For one thing, there seems to be no Neanderthal equivalent to the emergence of "Behavioral modernity" which took place @ 40,000 years ago with the Ancestors. Anatomically modern Humans had been around for roughly 200,000 years, but until 40,000 years ago, they showed no signs of culture or inventiveness. Neanderthal sites show no cultural flowering at all until after the time when they were co located or interacting with the Ancestors. After that time, they suddenly have more advanced tools such as awls to make fitted clothing and so on.

Another conjectural item is the social structure of the Neanderthal. It seems they lived in much smaller groupings than the Ancestors, so how they interacted with each other and with strangers is difficult to determine. It may well be they were unable to function in the sorts of larger family, clan and tribal arrangements that the Ancestors favoured. This had potentially fatal consequences if a single individual died or was incapacitated. There would be a much greater shortage of manpower to do all the things needed should one person die, and if the individual happened to have a vital position in the clan grouping (i.e. toolmaker or knowledge of healing plants and medicine), then the entire clan might be helpless in the face of a very hostile environment. The small size of these groups would also put them at a disadvantage when the Ancestors arrived, since larger clans and tribal groups would consume far more resources, potentially starving out the Neanderthal tribes in the area.

One does not really have to invoke warfare between the Ancestors and the Neanderthals as a reason for extinction, although conflict over resources was quite possible. The Ancestors seem to have been the original party animals, quite willing to trade, teach by example and even intermarry or interbreed with their Neanderthal cousins. If a tiny Neanderthal group were to lose a person and starve in the middle of an ice age winter, the Homo Sapiens in the next valley might not even be aware of this until spring.

Advancing into modern times would be difficult if these small groups with limited interaction continued to thrive or were the only Human species on Earth. It is not clear why modern humans suddenly developed culture 20,000 years ago, so if the Neanderthal didn't have someone to teach them or to copy from, they did not *seem* to have the ability to spontaneously create and invent. Small social groupings would be more difficult to grow into critical masses for building, trade or even tackling large projects like irrigation or building pyramids.

If these assumptions are correct, then the Neanderthal, without either some mutation or external force to drive them, may well remain as a neolithic hunter-gatherer and only live in widely scattered bands throughout the world. Their major adaptations for muscular mass, large noses and sinuses and a stocky body plan were adaptations top meet the severe cold environment of Ice Age Europe. In the interglacial period, some of these adaptations might gradually be lost, but would be kept in the gene pool should conditions change again (Homo Sapiens has that ability as well, consider the morphology of the Massi compared to the Inuit. If you were stuck in that environment, your descendants would gradually change to match, becoming taller and thinner in the savannah environment of the Massi or round and fat in the high arctic like the Inuit people).